# Crontab python script does not run (with anaconda on linux server)

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron

I have the following list of tasks to complete and they are working successfully.

```
0 0 */1 * *  bash /home/user/Code/agapov/start_GHR_Y00011285.sh >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
5 0 */1 * *  bash /home/user/Code/agapov/start_GHR_Y00011280.sh >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
10 0 */1 * *  bash /home/user/Code/agapov/start_GHR_Y10001320.sh >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
20 0 */1 * *  bash /home/user/Code/agapov/aggregation.sh >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
25 0 */1 * *  bash /home/user/Code/ivanov/start_API_N00001010.sh >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
```

The file structure is as follows:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 source /home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate
 python /home/user/Code/agapov/GHR_Y00011280.py 
 conda deactivate
```

But then a problem arises, I added several new files for execution and they do not work. Here is an example of the code for such a file

```
 #!/bin/bash
 source /home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate
 python /home/user/Code/analyzator.py 
 conda deactivate
```

As you can see, it is completely similar, the python file itself starts and does its job perfectly, but something goes wrong with the crowns

Cron logs:

```
/home/user/Code/start_analyzator.sh: line 4: conda: command not found
/home/user/Code/start_analyzator.sh: line 2: /home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate
: No such file or directory
/home/user/Code/start_analyzator.sh: line 3: python: command not found
bash: /home/user/Code/ivanov/start_DS_N00001400.sh: No such file or directory
/home/user/Code/start_analyzator.sh: line 4: conda: command not found
/home/user/Code/start_analyzator.sh: line 2: /home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate
: No such file or directory
/home/user/Code/start_analyzator.sh: line 3: python: command not found
/home/user/Code/start_analyzator.sh: line 4: conda: command not found
```

analyzator - a file that sends a message to a telegram, here are its settings for checking

```
*/5 * * * * bash /home/user/Code/start_analyzator.sh >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
```

What could be the problem, some files work fine and others don't???

Comment: Looks like you need to set the PATH variable in your cron job.

Comment: Did you create the shell script on a windows machine?

Comment: @RamanSailopal everything is configured, there were no such problems before, the old settings work successfully. it seems that is not the case

Comment: @tink Yes, I work through Moba, a computer running Windows 10

Comment: Convert the file to unix line endings ...

Comment: @tink Something I'm a little frozen, but how to do it? just don't throw stones)

Comment: @tink it is work, thanks a lot, I just copied to google and copied back to the file

Comment: Have a look at `man dos2unix`.  If that doesn't exist, something like this might work (assuming that you don't have any valid embedded CR)  `tr -d '\r' <input >output`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're suffering from DOS line-endings inside your shell script, the CR gets interpreted as part of the file name, which indeed does not exist.

One way of dealing with this would be to use a linux editor; another way would be to use

```
dos2unix < infile > outfile
```