# How to run my Python script with Anaconda environment in crontab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, anaconda

- I want to scedual a task with crontab to run a python file in a specific anaconda environment every day at a certain time.
- I also have a python script to do so.
- The pythons script runs if I jsut execute it with `python h.py` in the anaconda evoronment in terminal. h.py is in the home directory
- I am usaing Ubuntu 20.04, and i havent refreshed on intalled any new cron or crontab
- I have tried the following commands to get it work but they just do Nothing (the result should be a folder and it is learly not has been created)

```
crontab -e
```

**Inside the crontab:**

```
#[long descriptional text]
...
53 13 * * * cd /home/ && /home/user/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python h.py
```

this alos does nothing no error message

I have also tried the following solutions

- `32 14 * * * cd /home/Documents && /home/user/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python h.py`
- `34 14 * * * cd /home/Documents && /home/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python h.py 2>&1` https://stackoverflow.com/a/64470729/10270590
- `44 14 * * * cd /home/Documents && /home/user/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python h.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1`
- not worked with normal anaconda - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572951/400960
- `58 14 * * * /home/Documents && /home/user/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python home/Documents/h.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1`
- `59 14 * * * /home/Documents && /home/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python home/Documents/h.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1`
- `58 14 * * * /home/user/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python home/Documents/h.py`
- `10 15  * * * /home/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python home/Documents/h.py`
- Run this for analytics purpose with no results (no file has been created, no printout in terminal) `36 15 * * * /home/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('out\n'); sys.stderr.write('err\n')" >> /home/so_test.log 2>&1`

I have also read teh following solutions but nothing have realy worked

- 1 thinga that may someve that issue is taht I am not sure if I need to isntall a daemon for crontab, like it recomended here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1048365/984498 but I culd not find  cronie install for ubuntu
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/300128/how-can-i-run-a-python-script-using-anaconda-from-the-command-line
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574085/crontab-service-file-not-found-despite-installed-and-configured-crontab
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021622/crontab-doesnt-run-python-script
- [Execute Python script via crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-via-crontab)
- [Crontab python script does not run (with anaconda on linux server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65904501/crontab-python-script-does-not-run-with-anaconda-on-linux-server)

Comment: You should use the full path of the python script too e.g: `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python /home/h.py`. There's no need to `cd`, if you need to be in `/home` you should [set the `cwd` in the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/equivalent-of-shell-cd-command-to-change-the-working-directory).

Comment: Thank you I have modified it to this ```58 14 * * * /home/Documents && /home/user/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python home/Documents/h.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1``` I dont undestand teh links you jsut sent can you describe what exactly I should do?

Comment: You do not need to do anything before the command. So the full cron line should be: `58 14 * * * /home/user/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python home/Documents/h.py` with whatever output redirects you want. You should probably also expand the `~` for the log. The link I gave is how to change the current working directory of a python script, it is the equivalent of `cd` but within a python script.

Comment: Still nothing happens (added it to the tried solutions). Is there a was to gget an error message becasue this also doesent prints out to my terminal anything ```>> ~/cron.log 2>&```

Comment: `* 15 * * * /home/user/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('out\n'); sys.stderr.write('err\n')" >> /home/user/so_test.log 2>&1` this works and outputs both `stdout` and `stderr` to the file `/home/user/so_test.log`.  Try adding this to your crontab and see if it runs

Comment: Do I need the ```/user/``` part becsaue my anaconda folder is in the home folder directly.

Comment: You should know the path to your python executable, if you've activated your environment run `which python` and that will tell you where the executable file is. That should be the first item after the time spec, for me it's `/home/alex/envs/test_env/bin/python`. yours will be different. I have copied the path that _you_ have given in your question!

Comment: Also, in your updated examples you are missing the first `/` on the path to your python script.

Comment: ```10 15  * * * /home/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python home/Documents/h.py``` -> ```10 15  * * * /home/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python /home/Documents/h.py```

Comment: Generated no files no printouts ```* 15 * * * /home/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('out\n'); sys.stderr.write('err\n')" >> /home/so_test.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233052/discussion-between-alex-and-sogu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If the Python file only need python (not other library)**

```
56 16 * * * /home/MY_ACTUAL_USERNAME/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python /home/MY_ACTUAL_USERNAME/Documents/h.py
```

**If Python file requires other python libraries that is in the anaconda environment:**

- create a SHELL script

```
nano my_sehell_file_name.sh
```

- Example what should be inside the file

```
#!/bin/bash
#conda activate rapids WRONG
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate MY_ANACONDA_ENVIRONMENT_NAME #correct
#python Documents/my_python_file_name.py WRONG SEPARATLY GO TO FOLER WHTAN EXECUTE EITH python
cd ~/Documents/folder_where_python_file_is/ #correct
python my_python_file_name.py #correct
conda deactivate
```

- start up corntab by

`corntab -e`

- ex what you can write to the end of this corntab file

```
43 21 * * * /home/MY_ACTUAL_USERNAME/my_sehell_file_name.sh
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding this line works for miniconda as well :)
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate MY_ANACONDA_ENVIRONMENT_NAME